# Windows Version Using GetProductInfo

Tags: delphi

I am trying to Display Windows Version and Product Details for Vista onwards OS using [`GetProductInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724358) Function in Delphi XE2 as suggested by one Senoir Member. I have defined the following codes but I am not able to compile it. My codes as follows :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
TGetProductInfoAPI = function(dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion,
dwSpMajorVersion, dwSpMinorVersion: DWORD; pdwReturnedProductType:
PDWORD): BOOL stdcall;
begin
  Edit1.Text:=IntToStr(dwOSMajorVersion);
  Edit2.Text:=IntToStr(dwOSMinorVersion);
  Edit3.Text:=IntToStr(dwSpMajorVersion);
  Edit4.Text:=IntToStr(dwSpMinorVersion);
  Edit5.Text:=TGetProductInfoAPI.pdwReturnedProductType;
end;

end.
```

I think I am doing some mistakes but I am unable to find It. Please tell me where I am making mistake.

Comment: You never call a function at all.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `kernel32.dll` is to write

```
function GetProductInfo(dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion, dwSpMajorVersion,
  dwSpMinorVersion: DWORD; out pdwReturnedProductType: DWORD): BOOL stdcall;
  external kernel32 delayed;
```

in some unit (outside of any procedure, type declaration, etc.)

For example,

```
function GetProductInfo(dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion, dwSpMajorVersion,
  dwSpMinorVersion: DWORD; out pdwReturnedProductType: DWORD): BOOL stdcall;
  external kernel32 delayed;

const
  PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM = $00000003;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rpt: cardinal;
begin
  if GetProductInfo(6, 1, 0, 0, rpt) then
    if rpt and PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM <> 0 then
      ShowMessage('Yeah, you''re running Home Premium.');
end;
```

If you just want to see the returned value, well, just display it!

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rpt: cardinal;
begin
  if GetProductInfo(6, 1, 0, 0, rpt) then
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(rpt));
end;
```

Also, just to make things clear: The four first arguments to this function are (obviously) for *input*, not for *output*. If you want to get the version of the OS, you could use [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or simply have a look at the variables `Win32MajorVersion` etc. in `SysUtils`.

Comment: No no ! My requirement is show the return value only. I will encode it in my way. Please tell me the procedure to show only the return value

Comment: The problem with this is that the EXE won't load on XP. You want a version check `CheckWin32Version(6)` and the use of `delayed`.

Comment: @RubiHalder: All you need is in my answer.

Comment: @TLama: Yes, that would be more Delphi-ish, and more typesafe.

Comment: After compiling the abobe code for displaying return value, I am able to show "pdwReturnedProductType" value only but not able to show the value of "dwOSMajorVersion", "dwOSMinorVersion", "dwSpMajorVersion" and "dwSpMinorVersion" though they are [in] parameter, ofcource there should be any way to show them.

Comment: @Rubi: I think you have completely misunderstood what this function does. Read the documentation I refered to, and my last comment.

Comment: And there sould be a checking so that "GetProductInfo" will be called if "IntToStr(TOSVersion.Major)>=6" else "TOSVersion" will act.

Comment: @Rubi Yes there should. Do feel free to do that yourself. Remember that if you want your exe to run on XP then you need to add `delayed` to the function declaration. @Andreas Couldn't you make such an edit?

Comment: @David: I added the keyword. [Since I am still using D2009, I'm forced to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, and so I'm not used to this new keyword.]

Comment: @RubiHalder We cannot sit at your keyboard and type the code for you. I already provided the version check that you need. It is `CheckWin32Version(6)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if I remember correctly CheckWin32Version was broken in Delphi 6 (it returned false when the version was higher). [Docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_CheckWin32Version.html) mention only " Prior to Delphi 7, this routine returned a different result"